# Flexbox ordering, equivalent of getnextElementSibling to get next element in order not next item in DOM

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I understand why this doesn't work after the first press of any button, it's because `nextElementSibling()` gets the next element in the DOM rather than the next element in the flexbox ordering.  What I don't know is how to fix it.

Any ideas?  (BTW there is a reason I wanted to use flexbox ordering and not just manipulate the order of elements in the DOM).

```js
function down(me) {
  
  //get current posistions
  
  var upper=me.parentElement;
  var lower=me.parentElement.nextElementSibling;
  
  initialupper=upper.getBoundingClientRect();
  initiallower=lower.getBoundingClientRect();
  
  //do actual reorder
  
  upper.style.order++;
  lower.style.order--;
  
  //reverse appearance of reorder
  
  finalupper=upper.getBoundingClientRect();
  finallower=lower.getBoundingClientRect();
  
  const deltaYupper = initialupper.top - finalupper.top;
  const deltaYlower = initiallower.top - finallower.top;
 
  upper.style.transform = `translateY(${deltaYupper}px)`;
  lower.style.transform = `translateY(${deltaYlower}px)`;
  
  //do transistion from reversed apperance to erm.. 'actual hidden appearance'
  
  requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    upper.classList.add("slide");
    lower.classList.add("slide");
    lower.style.transform = "";
    upper.style.transform = "";
    me.parentElement.addEventListener('transitionend',function(e) {
      upper.classList.remove("slide");
      lower.classList.remove("slide");
    });
  });
}
```

```css
#container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.slide {
  transition: transform 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div style="order: 1;">Element 1 <button onclick="down(this)">Down</button></div>
  <div style="order: 2;">Element 2 <button onclick="down(this)">Down</button></div>
  <div style="order: 3;">Element 3 
    <br/>Double Height<button onclick="down(this)">Down</button></div>
  <div style="order: 4;">Element 4 <button onclick="down(this)">Down</button></div>
  <div style="order: 5;">Element 5 <button onclick="down(this)">Down</button></div>
</div>
```

EDIT

Here is a version that works properly using DOM maniplualtion.

```js
function down(me) {
  
  //get current posistions
  
  var upper=me.parentElement;
  var lower=me.parentElement.nextElementSibling;
  
  initialupper=upper.getBoundingClientRect();
  initiallower=lower.getBoundingClientRect();
  
  //do actual reorder
  
  lower.after(upper);
  
  //reverse appearance of reorder
  
  finalupper=upper.getBoundingClientRect();
  finallower=lower.getBoundingClientRect();
  
  const deltaYupper = initialupper.top - finalupper.top;
  const deltaYlower = initiallower.top - finallower.top;
 
  upper.style.transform = `translateY(${deltaYupper}px)`;
  lower.style.transform = `translateY(${deltaYlower}px)`;
  
  //do transistion from reversed apperance to erm.. 'actual hidden appearance'
  
  requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    upper.classList.add("slide");
    lower.classList.add("slide");
    lower.style.transform = "";
    upper.style.transform = "";
    me.parentElement.addEventListener('transitionend',function(e) {
      upper.classList.remove("slide");
      lower.classList.remove("slide");
    });
  });
}
```

```css
<div id="container">
  <div>Element 1 <button onclick="down(this)">Down</button></div>
  <div>Element 2 <button onclick="down(this)">Down</button></div>
  <div>Element 3 <br/>Double Height<button onclick="down(this)">Down</button></div>
  <div>Element 4 <button onclick="down(this)">Down</button></div>
  <div>Element 5 <button onclick="down(this)">Down</button></div>
</div>
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>Element 1 <button onclick="down(this)">Down</button></div>
  <div>Element 2 <button onclick="down(this)">Down</button></div>
  <div>Element 3 <br/>Double Height<button onclick="down(this)">Down</button></div>
  <div>Element 4 <button onclick="down(this)">Down</button></div>
  <div>Element 5 <button onclick="down(this)">Down</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not use the JS to read the `order` property and then swap the property value? Or is there something more complex than that?

Comment: @disinfor swap it with what?  Without knowing the next element in the order I don't know what to swap it with.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking then. Your example shows your elements with an ascending `order` property. Can you update your example to show what the situation is you are actually trying to solve? Or are you simply saying that you want to change the `order` property when you move an element down?

Comment: @disinfor run the example code.  Click on the first item in the list, you'll see a transition and it will swap with the second item it the list.  Click on the top item in the list again and the transition won't work.  Then again and crazy things happen.  I will post a working example using DOM replacement.

Comment: Ah..ok, I see what's happening now. Makes more sense.